# I am not getting data at server side request.post()

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

> I am new at Aiohttp and here is a client code for populating data. Below a server code for recieving data. But at server end I am getting KeyError. Also see print(len(request.post()) @ server is 0. But this server code works with Postman testing. And this client code works well with "/httpbin/post/" request. What is wrong with this code. helps appreciated very much.

## AT CLIENT SIDE

```
BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:9001/"
headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
data = {'username': 'achama', 'password': 'password'}

register_endpoint = "register"


jar = aiohttp.CookieJar(unsafe=True)

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(json_serialize=ujson.dumps, cookie_jar=jar) as session:
        async with session.post(url=BASE_URL+register_endpoint, json=data, headers=headers) as resp:
            resp_data = await resp.json(content_type=None)
            print(resp_data)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
# Zero-sleep to allow underlying connections to close
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(0))
loop.close()
```

## AT SERVER

async def register(self, request):
    print(len(await request.post()))

```
posted_data = await request.post()
user_id = await db.get_user_id(self.mongo.loginhub, 
posted_data['username'])
if user_id is None:
    hashed_password = generate_password_hash(posted_data['password'])
        await self.mongo.loginhub.insert_one(
            {'username': posted_data['username'],
             'current_password': hashed_password, 
             'last_password': ""})
        unique_id = await db.get_user_id(self.mongo.loginhub, posted_data['username'])
        await self.mongo.users.insert_one(
            {'unique_id': unique_id, 'username': posted_data['username'], 
            "joined_date": datetime.utcnow(), "active": False})
        return json_response({"message": f"Your account created with {posted_data['username']} Please login to use."})
    else:
        return json_response({"Error": f"Username {posted_data['username']} already exists. Please choose another one."})
```

## SERVER SIDE ERROR

> File "/home/bijuknarayan/workspace/aio/marryapp/backend/auth.py",
>   line 44, in register
>       user_id = await db.get_user_id(self.mongo.loginhub, posted_data['username'])   File "multidict/_multidict.pyx", line 62,
>   in multidict._multidict._Base.**getitem**   File
>   "multidict/_multidict.pyx", line 57, in
>   multidict._multidict._Base._getone   File "multidict/_multidict.pyx",
>   line 52, in multidict._multidict._Base._getone KeyError: 'username'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `await request.post()` with `await request.json()` on the server side if you want to handle JSON data.

Comment: But with postman testing with body/form-data or raw .its not working. how can both will work.